# War file will not show images/CSS/JS/HTML

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, war

I am working on a spring-MVC project. Right now I have a user.jsp file which is responsible for adding users in the database. I have created a few images, js, css to go with it. As you can guess, the HTML code is within the .jsp code. Once I land on the page, I can see all my HTML code working, but no CSS, no images. I have checked, and all images,etc are in my war file too. In the IDE, when I click on any CSS or any JS file, it takes me there. I am presuming, it means that it is able to find the link with the absolute path I provided. Then why am I unable to see that when I run the application? Structure is as follows:

```
webapp/
|--+views/
         css/
         fonts/
         img/
    |+-user.jsp
```

Also, When i open the war file with archive manager and all the folders outside the project, then all the files are parsed.

JSP code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>

<head>

    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Ecommerce</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,700,900,700italic,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/perfect-scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chosen.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello-ie7.css">
    <![endif]-->

</head>


<body>

<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">

<!-- Header -->
<header class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

<!-- Top Header -->
<div id="top-header">

    <div class="row">

        <nav id="top-navigation" class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="create_an_account.html">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="orders_list.html">List Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="order_info.html">Checkout</a></li>
                <li><a href="text_page.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Thats just a little bit of JSP code to get idea.

Comment: What is the the response you are getting?

Comment: Hello, The application runs, I just cant see any images or any stylesheets being implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You are having relative path for your css this will only work for one purticular path, in your case it will work only if the URL of the page is `<context>/views/user.jsp`.

To solve this you have to append the context root like in the below example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Oh my, there are are a heck load of files, any other option you have? Thanks man.